# How to using multi threading to get data from same table in several databases using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

This method get paths from several databases slowly. I want using multi threading to get paths very fast from several database. 'CnnStr' is connection string of 'Sellers'. I want create web service but i using sample this code in project and this slowed down my website.

```
public static List<IdTitle> GetPathes(string srcCity)
{
   List<SellerInfo> sellers = GetSellers();
   List<IdTitle> res = new List<IdTitle>();
   List<string> hash = new List<string>();
   for (int i = 0; i < sellers.Count; i++)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sellers[i].CnnStr) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sellers[i].EUrl))
        continue;
       List<IdTitle> pathes = GetPathes(sellers[i], srcCity);
       if (pathes == null || pathes.Count == 0)
           continue;
       for (int j = 0; j < pathes.Count; j++)
          if (!hash.Contains(pathes[j].Title))
          {
              hash.Add(pathes[j].Title);
              res.Add(pathes[j]);
          }
   }
   return res;
}

public static List<IdTitle> GetPathes(SellerInfo info, string srcCity)
{
    if (info == null)
        return null;
    string qry = @"SELECT Paths.ID, City1.Title + N' -> ' + City2.Title AS Title FROM
                    Paths INNER JOIN Cities AS City1 ON Paths.SrcCityID=City1.ID
                    INNER JOIN Cities AS City2 ON Paths.DestCityID=City2.ID";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(srcCity))
        qry += " WHERE City1.Title="+DbHelper.QtdStr(srcCity);
    try
    {
       IDataReader dr = DbHelper.Instance.ExecuteReader(info.CnnStr, qry);
       return ObjectBinder.FillCollection<IdTitle>(dr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       AddLog(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you already have a `for` loop, the simplest option seems to be calling `Parallel.For`.

Comment: obligatory SQL injection comment; your code right now is **actively dangerous** - I could hack your database by choosing my city carefully. Please please look into SQL parameters and parameterization. Now, I'm off to complete my move to `Chicago' delete from Cities --`

Comment: Since your operation is I/O bound its generally better to use I/O completion ports (IOCP) such as `Beginxxx` or `async/await` (if used with I/O operations) rather than spinning up explicit threads.  Such threads will only block on I/O which is kinda a waste of a thread

Comment: @MarcGravell: In 2018 can we *really* call taking advantage of SQL Injection, "hacking"?  These days, 2 decades since SQL injection was publicly disclosed, wouldn't SQL Injection be called "using"?  With all of those YEARS.. and all the resources out there that helps people avoid SQLi, if someone has an injection "vulnerability" it MUST be there on purpose.  I think as of today I'm going to start thinking of SQLi as a feature that the developer intends for me to use.

Comment: @MarcGravell: In fact, I believe SQLi should be considered *good* programming.  Best practice even.  It brings modern OOP to databases:  User-driven polymorphism :)

Comment: @SamAxe I usually base "hacking" on the "could this get me charged under the Computer Misuse Act 1990" test (since I'm in the UK); and in the case of SQLi, the answer would be "yes" :)

Comment: I edit my query please help me on sample code to solved my problem.

Comment: There is asynchronous execution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k(v=vs.110).aspx.  But I am not sure what happens if you fire multiple and don't wait for the callback.